# use lib db4o on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, db4o

Before I used to use db4o-8.1.317.16154-core-java5 on Eclipse, by addthe jar in the lib folder. Now I want to use Android Studio, but the problem I can't find the compile dependence to put in Gradle to download db4o

What dependence do I have to use, to get this lib downloaded on Android Studio.

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know db4o is not published on Maven central. Therefore, Gradle cannot find it there.

You need to put db4o into a library directory as before. Then add tell Gradle to pick the library up from there.

You are on the right way, the `compie fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` should do it. This tells Gradle to use all *.jar files in the 'libs' directory in your project.
Add the db4o jars into the 'libs' directory and it should be found.

Comment: Tnank you for your response, it's correct my problem.